# Back button for webpage loaded in object tag

Tags: javascript, object

```
<a onclick="contentarea.history.back()"><img src="images/template-center-back-btn.png" /></a>

<object type="text/html" data="" name="contentarea" id="contentarea"></object>
```

I need this image to operate as a back button for the webpages loaded in the object tag but I can't seem to get it to work.

All help appreciated.

Comment: What problem you are facing ? Image is not visible ? OR backbutton is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work out for you**

//index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>


<a href="" onclick="goBack()"><img src="images/template-center-back-btn.png" /></a>
   //try this also
    <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)"><img src="images/template-center-back-btn.png" /></a>

    <object type="text/html" data="" name="contentarea" id="contentarea"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

History is something which we can call it as "global" object. It can not be associated with the `divs` or `objects`, since it is associated with global `window` object. You should try this instead :

```
window.history.back();
```